# Using a different active directory tree in powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

So I have a script with the purpose of scanning devices that start with a certain name, then return results of computers missing a group.  My problem is, the device I need it to run from turns out not to be in the same tree.  I have seen some commands, but I wanted to be sure I had the syntax right.  I will include part of the script for context:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Group = "A-Certain-Group"
$Groupname = (Get-ADGroup $Group).distinguishedName
$Computers = Get-ADComputer -filter "name -like 'Big*'" -Prop MemberOf | Where{$_.MemberOf -notcontains $Groupname}
```

So let's say I am running it from "company.net", and it needs to perform the above script on "companynet.net" instead.  What is the proper method?

Answer (score 1):

The AD cmdlets all have a -server parameter which lets you specify other domains. Just use it to specify the other domain assuming there is a trust.

```
$Groupname = (Get-ADGroup $Group -Server companynet.net).distinguishedName
$Computers = Get-ADComputer -Server companynet.net -filter "name -like 'Big*'" -Prop MemberOf | Where{$_.MemberOf -notcontains $Groupname}
```

Note that if you don't have permission to perform actions in the domain you will also need to use the -credential parameter.

Comment: Wow, as easy as that was, I feel like an idiot.  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. The parameter is kinda misleading since you wouldn't think -server also accepts a domain name. Anyways, glad to help.